# StackOverflowError in bean on launching Springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.udemy.com/course/microservices-with-spring-boot-and-spring-cloud/learn/lecture/8005656#questions) on SpringBoot. And getting a StackOVerflowError while creating the bean localeResolver.

**Initializing the locale resolver in Springboot**

```
@Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        AcceptHeaderLocaleContextResolver localeResolver = new AcceptHeaderLocaleContextResolver();
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
        return localeResolver();
    }
```

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

**Error Log:**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'localeResolver' defined in com.in28minutes.springboot.basics.springbootin10steps.SpringbootIn10StepsApplication: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver]: Factory method 'localeResolver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:484) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at com.in28minutes.springboot.basics.springbootin10steps.SpringbootIn10StepsApplication.main(SpringbootIn10StepsApplication.java:21) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver]: Factory method 'localeResolver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.lang.String.indexOf(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.net.URLStreamHandler.parseURL(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.Handler.parseURL(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$FileLoader.getResource(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
```

I already the below steps:
1. commented out the devtools dependency : it didn't work
2. downgraded spring-boot-starter-parent: i still got the overflow error

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the same method here:

```
return localeResolver();
```

Just return object:

```
return localeResolver;
```

Comment: Thnkx! That's a bad mistake!